What are the fundamental differences of Kaplan-Meier testing versus tests of proportions?
Suppose my study will recruit 50 patients and monitor them for some outcome that may crop up at any point in time. My null hypothesis is that the proportion of event-free subjects at time $t=12$ is less than or equal to some benchmark ($\pi=0.2$). Suppose the true proportion at that time is 0.4. If we assume an exponential distribution of event arrival time, the survivor function can be solved for $\lambda = -\log(0.4)/12 = 0.076 $ events/month.
To define my response variable, I don't know (in my analysis) that event times are exponential. Also, my study terminates after some time, subjects are enrolled in a stepwise fashion, and may drop out before they've even been followed up to time $t$. So, the Kaplan-Meier methodology is the desired analysis framework. And we can compare the lower end of the 95% CI to the benchmark, if it exceeds it, then our test is significant at the 0.05 level. On the other hand, I can define a binary value to be 1 if a subject is followed for 6 months on-study and event free, 0 otherwise. Taking intercurrent events of censoring and study termination as a negative response is clearly more conservative in a single arm trial (SAT).
But how can I practically describe the difference between these two testing strategies to a reviewer?  Is/are there a well-defined (set of) term(s) to distinguish between these two definitions of seemingly similar endpoints? In the little simulation below, we see that as long as subjects can be followed reliably until the endpoint is observed, the KM curve approach has slightly higher power but still estimates the same proportion.
library(survival)
set.seed(123)
do.one <- function() {
  n <- 50
  t0 <- runif(50, 0, 6) ## recruit all n=50 over 6 months
  t1 <- rexp(50, 0.076)
  y <- Surv(time=pmin(t1, 18-t0), event=t1 < 18-t0)
  f <- survfit(y ~ 1)
  sf <- summary(f, conf.type='clog-log')
  
  c(
    'estSurvKM' = sf$surv[max(which(sf$time < 12))],
    'estProp' = sum((t1 > 12) & ((18-t0) > 12))/50,
    'sigSurvKM' = sf$lower[max(which(sf$time < 12))] > 0.2,
    'sigPropr' = prop.test(sum(t1 > 12 & (18-t0) > 12) , n=50, 
                    p=0.2)$p.value < 0.05
    )
}

val <- replicate(1000, do.one())
rowMeans(val)

> rowMeans(val)
estSurvKM   estProp sigSurvKM  sigPropr 
  0.40184   0.40184   0.91400   0.84500


Maybe I am missing something, but KM is generally a test of time to an event, proportion tests are tests of whether an event happens at all, in the time you have.

@PeterFlom the KM is actually the non-parametric estimate of the survivor function. In a two-sample test for differences in two (or more) KMs, you can use a log rank test. But I am interested in a one sample test. The KM has various standard error estimates for survival at a given timepoint. In my example, the test procedure involves using those SE estimates to conduct a Wald style test for the survival at a given timepoint- I just see if the LB is greater than my benchmark.
